# PHP how to query all rows from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a project that involves PHP and SQL. I have to query several columns in a table. For the first 2 columns 'nid' and 'vid' I got all the correct values. However, for the last column 'title' the query is only returning the 1st row for each. For example, there are nids 2, 3,4 and so on but some of these have more than 1 item in them. Instead of returning the title for each item of 2, 3, etc it only returns the 1st one. Why is that? Attached is a screenshot to show what I'm saying

```
$queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid, MAX(vid) as vid, title FROM node_revision GROUP BY nid";
    // line above creates variable $queryNodeRevision > 

    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNodeRevision) or die("Bad Query: $results");
    // line above creates variable $results > actually queries that database and passes in variable "$queryNodeRevision"

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      // line above creates while loop that loops through > $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)
      // $row is variable that's set to mysqli_fetch_array (with variable $results being passed in)
      // mysqli_fetch_array > creates an associate array for each row in a table
      // $results > variable that's being passed into associative array that represents the variable that's querying "SELECT nid FROM node_revision";
      $currentNID = $row['nid'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current 'nid' of row (aka the key)
      // $row['nid'] = gets the key # of the current 'nid'
      $currentVID = $row['vid'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current value of the 'vid' (the number you want to compare)
      // $row['vid'] = gets the value of the current 'vid'  
      $theTitleIWant = $row['title'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current value of the 'title'
      // $row['title'] = gets the value of the current 'title'  
      echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
      // line prints out desired 'title' into h1 tag
    } // line closes while loop
```

Below is the query line that's not targeting all the titles correctly:

```
$queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid, MAX(vid) as vid, title FROM node_revision GROUP BY nid";
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: `GROUP BY nid` compresses the results, so you're only going to get one row for each nid. If you want to get all of the titles, look in to [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would do that? I tried and I'm getting an even bigger error message.

Comment: Whoops, I actually meant [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Try `GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR '|') AS title`, and it will put all of the titles in a string separated by the `|` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

For your expected result there is no need of `Group by` clause.
Query as follow:

`SELECT nid, (select MAX(vid) from node_revision nr1 where nr1.nid=nid) as vid, title FROM node_revision nr2 where nr2.nid=3`

Hope this will help you